# Ant Build Issue: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ant, jboss, wsdl, wsdl2java

I'm new to Ant and this application. I'm not able to decode this error message.

```
C:\Eclipse\sources_int\external-sources>ant netstudy-generate-client
Buildfile: C:\Eclipse\sources_int\external-sources\build.xml

netstudy-generate-client:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Eclipse\ext_sources_int\external-sources\build\generated_classe
s
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Eclipse\sources_int\external-sources\build\generated_classes

     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/WSDLToJava
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
     [java] Could not find the main class: org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.  Program will exit.
     [java] Exception in thread "main"
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD FAILED
C:\Eclipse\sources_int\external-sources\build.xml:183: srcdir "C:\Eclipse\sources_int\
external-sources\build\generated_src" does not exist!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of the ant build is trying to run a Java application. the main class (the Java class that contains a main method) cannot be found.  check your path and make sure you are including the jar file that contains the class org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.

possibly it is expecting to find this class in the directory it cannot find.

Comment: This is the missing jar: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.cxf|cxf-tools-wsdlto-core|2.7.5|jar

Answer (score 0):

JBoss comes with wsconsume in order to generate the client. I was trying to enforce the use of wsdltojava but it didn't work and I have the same problem.
So try to use ***wsconsume*** .